# CSS Framework Which Supports Fluid Layouts

Tags: css, frameworks

Does anyone know of any CSS Framework(s) which supports Fluid Layouts?

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [blueprint css](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) which you can make fluid by combining it with [liquidgrid](http://github.com/Montoya/blueprint-plugin---liquidgrid/).

Comment: Does it support all browsers though? It looks like it breaks in IE7?